# apache rewrite to root without change or url

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, rewrite

the WordPress rewrite rules are like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

now i would like to add a new rule that would deliver for the url /test the same content as the root page, but without doing an actual redirect.

i have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^test/$ /index.php [PT]
```

but that does seem to give test as a parameter to index.php, since i get a page not found error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your new rule. Are you trying to access 'whatever.com/test/' or are you trying to do 'whatever.com/test/whatever'?

The rule you have will only match for 'whatever.com/test/' and not 'whatever.com/test/index.html'.

If you wanted it to do all, then change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^test/$ /index.php [PT]
RewriteRule ^test/.*$ /index.php [PT]
```

Comment: i am trying to access /test/. it seems it works if i specify another file like a.php, but not with index.php. i guess it is a WordPress problem.